# Detecting when call had been answered using Dial verb

Tags: twilio

I need a way to find out when an outgoing call has been answered when using the dial twiml verb so I can notify the user making the call. I know I can get the status after the call has ended with the action param but that is not what I need. Is there a way to lookup the status of a live call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the 'url' attribute of the <Number> tag.  This is requested after the Dial leg is answered but before the two calls are joined.  You can return the minimal TwiML response <Response/> for this url if you don't want any action to take place on call.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url