# Twillio Call Screening - Dial stops ringing

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio's call screening / whisper example. So basically when we use the Dial verb to call the number, we want to play a message when the receiver picks up the phone and give them the option to accept/reject the call. While the caller should keep hearing the ringing tone until the receiver makes a choice.

Most of this works as expected if we follow what's described in the call screening example https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callscreening

The problem is as soon as the receiver picks the phone, the caller can no longer hear the ringing tone, and the call goes silence until we have a response back from the receiver. This is a huge problem, because the caller will probably hang up once the ringing tone stops and there is no answer.

I have already had a look at the following two answers.

[Twillio Call Screening silence on answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504427/twillio-call-screening-silence-on-answer)

[Detecting when call had been answered using Dial verb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234361/detecting-when-call-had-been-answered-using-dial-verb?rq=1)

I personally don't want to go down the conference route.

In Number verb's documentation its clearly mentioned that the caller will continue to hear ringing tone.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url

> The 'url' attribute allows you to specify a url for a TwiML document that will run on the called party's end, after she answers, but before the parties are connected. You can use this TwiML to privately play or say information to the called party, or provide a chance to decline the phone call using Gather and Hangup. **The current caller will continue to hear ringing while the TwiML document executes on the other end.** TwiML documents executed in this manner are not allowed to contain the Dial verb.

The same issue happens with the Find Me Twimlet as well.

twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme

Answer (score 0):

Contacted Twilio support, you'll need to set "ringTone" attribute on  like this:

```
<Dial answerOnBridge="true" ringTone="us">
```

I have tried that and it worked for me.